# How do I fulton an enemy

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-online

In Metal Gear Online, is the fulton tied to a specific class? Do I have to unlock and equip a specific support item? I've been standing next to a stunned/sleeping enemy but not seen a prompt to fulton them.

Maybe I wasn't standing in quite the right spot or the stun/sleep hadn't registered due to lag?

I'm playing Scout on Xbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fultoning an enemy in MGO works very similar to the main game, and to my knowledge can be done in any game mode by any class. Stand near a stunned or sleeping enemy and hold triangle/Y when the prompt appears. That being said, with MGO I've had a few issues with this command not always registering. The control scheme seems to prefer climbing onto something to using the fulton, and typically the command prompt takes half a second or more to even appear due to latency. Finally, during the time between an enemy being downed and you fultoning them your teammates can either kill the enemy or fulton them before you (I had a 10+ bounty which I incapacitated solo stolen from me... I swore quite a bit).

Comment: So it doesn't matter what class or game mode I'm playing - I should be able to fulton a stunned enemy provided I'm stood in the right place and the lag isn't playing up?

Comment: I've mainly played Bounty Hunter, but to my knowledge it should be available in any of the game modes as it's the only way for a nonlethal loadout to permanently neutralize an enemy. I'll edit that in.